# GNU override target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm wondering if it's possible to override a target in a makefile!  The environment I'm working in does not allow me to do this due to auto generation!  I was wondering if I coded the same rule above or below the static target would this achieve an override?

```
%_emul.flist: $(if ${GEN_FLIST},%_synth.flist,) ${rdlh_file_deps}
    ${QUIET}if test ${SYN_DEBUG} -eq 1 ; then set -xv ; fi; \
    $(if ${TOOL_VERILOG},rm -f $@; touch $@,$(if ${TOOL_BBOX_LIBS},echo ${TOOL_BBOX_LIBS} > $@,rm -f $@; touch $@))
    /bin/sed -e '/\/libs\//d' -e '/\/place\//d' $(foreach mod,$(filter %.vhd,$^),-e 's%^\(.*\/\)\{0,1\}$(basename $(notdir ${mod}))\.v$$%${mod}%') $*_synth.flist >> $@
```

Comment: Hmmmm possibly (but not the way you are thinking) can you post a  snippet of the rules that you wish to override?

Comment: @AhmedMasud Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Do you want to override the whole pattern rule (`%_emul.flist:...`)? Or just the rule for a particular target (`foo_emul.flist:...`)?

Comment: Yeah the whole rule!  I put my custom target lower down in the Makefile than it's implementation and it seems to have worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , i think that would work .... but you need to be a bit more careful in the way you code things. You don't want to override something that might be useful!

GNU make would take the most recent of the target it encounters. So, the following works (but not as i would have liked it to work :( )

Output: I think you are looking for something like this --

```
Kaizen ~/make_prac $  make -nf mk.name
mk.name:20: warning: overriding recipe for target `name'
mk.name:17: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `name'
arg1="Kaizen" ;
echo "hello "" ;" ;
hello  ;
```

Code: Here the target "name" appears twice and is overridden.

```
Kaizen ~/make_prac $ cat mk.name
##
## make to accept name and display hello name
##

arg1="" ;

.PHONY : name \
  hello

#.DEFAULT :
#       hello

hello : name
        + echo "hello $(arg1)" ;

name :
        echo "name given is : $(arg1)" ;

name :
        arg1="Kaizen" ;
```

PS: Take note of the use of `:` -- if you use `::` then both rules get executed.

Explanation for the `arg1 ....` not showing in the output: The variable `arg1`, even though it gets assigned in the first parsing, it gets ignored, since its assignment is target dependent. If you would have had a variable declaration elsewhere -- e.g. like `arg1` is defined at the start -- there would not be any dereferencing issues.

Comment: Would it be possible for one of the two to have a single colon and the other that I coded a double colon?

Comment: no , you can use either : for both the rules or :: for both , not a combination. The Make isin't that intelligent yet

Comment: GNU-Make [specifically disallows this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding-Makefiles.html). Additionally I think this demonstration is faulty because the variable scoping isn't right. Especially without `.ONESHELL` this sort of assignment wouldn't work even if `make` was consistent in how it parses this. In my testing it is possible to make it work sometimes with simple mock-ups like this but in cases where dependency trees are involved or parallel processing happens it all falls apart and you can't be sure which target will be called.